# Adjusting css file for new html menu

Tags: html, css, mobile, menu, desktop

this might be a bit complicated but I really need some help here..

I made a HTML menu and a css file for it. This was for a desktop version of my website.

I was in need of a mobile menu and due to my low skills of html and css, I asked a friend to make a mobile css file for the menu.

He ended up changing a little bit of code of the original HTML menu, this means that the mobile version is working, but I have to update my original css file for desktop a bit.

That's where the problem is, I just can't get it done, I can't find the right tag to update the file.

Original Desktop HTML menu and css file

```css
body {
        font-family: Raleway;
        margin: 0;
    }

    main {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 1280px;
    }

    /*Menu*/

    ul.menu {
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }

    label.show-menu {
        display: none;
    }

    input.show-menu {
        display: none;
    }


a:visited {
        border: none;
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
ul.menu > ul {
    margin-left: 80px;
    border: none;

}
ul.menu > ul li
 {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 80px;
}
ul.menu > ul {
    position: relative;

}
ul.menu > ul li {
    font-size: 30px;
    min-height: 1px;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    padding: 10px;
}
ul.menu > ul ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
ul.menu > ul ul li {
    float: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 30px;
}

ul.menu > ul li:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
ul.menu > ul li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
}


ul.menu ul > li > ul > li {
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
ul.menu ul > li > ul > li > a {
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
    display: block;
}

 #Logo {
        float: left;
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 56px;
        height: 79px;
    }
```

```html
<header>
        <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Menu</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" class="show-menu" role="button">

        <div id="Logo"><img src="Images/logo.png" alt="logo"></div>
        <nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
            <ul id="menu" class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">informatie</a>
                    <ul id="navinformatie">
                        <li><a  href="#">algemene info</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">wijken</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">goed om te weten</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">verblijf</a>
                    <ul id="navverblijf">
                        <li><a href="#">hotels</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">hostels</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">bezienswaardigheden</a>
                    <ul id="navbezienswaardigheden">
                        <li class="dir"><a href="#">toers</a></li>
                        <li class="dir"><a href="#">entertainment</a></li>
                        <li class="dir"><a href="#">musicals</a></li>
                        <li class="dir"><a href="#">sport</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
                </ul>
        </nav>
        </header>
```

The new HTML menu and mobile css file for it

```css
body {
        margin: 0;
    }

    main {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 480px;
    }

    /*menu*/

    ul{
        list-style-type:none;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        position: static;
        display: none;
    }

    li {
        display:inline-block;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 1px;
        border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;
    }

    li a {
        display:block;
        min-width:180px;
        height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 50px;
        color: black;
        background: white;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    li:hover a {
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }

    li:hover ul a {
        background: #f3f3f3;
        color: #2f3036;
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
    }

    /*Hover state for dropdown links*/
    li:hover ul a:hover {
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }

    /*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
    li ul {
        display: none;
    }

    /*Make dropdown links vertical*/
    li ul li {
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }

    li ul li a {
        width: auto;
        min-width: 100px;
        padding: 0 20px;
        text-align:center;

    }


    ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
        display: block;
    }

    #Logo {
        display: none;
    }

    .show-menu {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        background: black;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
        display: block;
    }

    input[type=checkbox]{
        display: none;
    }

    input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
        display: block;
    }


    ul li, li a {
        width: 100%;
        text-align:left;
    }
    ul li a{
        padding:0 10px;
    }

    li ul li a {
        text-align:center;
    }
```

```html
<header>
     <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Menu</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">

        <div id="Logo"><img src="logo.png" alt="logo"></div>
            <ul id="menu" class="mobile-top">
                <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">informatie</a>
                    <ul class="hidden">
                        <li><a  href="#">algemene info</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">wijken</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">goed om te weten</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">verblijf</a>
                    <ul class="hidden">
                        <li><a href="#">hotels</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">hostels</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">bezienswaardigheden</a>
                    <ul class="hidden">
                        <li class="dir"><a href="#">toers</a></li>
                        <li class="dir"><a href="#">entertainment</a></li>
                        <li class="dir"><a href="#">musicals</a></li>
                        <li class="dir"><a href="#">sport</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </header>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

So what I need now is some help to adjust the desktop css file to the new html menu, I can't figure it out where to start and what I should change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use media queries to apply a different set of CSS for mobile and desktop. You could wrap your original css like this, to only apply the desktop CSS when the width is bigger than 600px.

```
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  body {
        font-family: Raleway;
        margin: 0;
    }

    main {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 1280px;
    }

    /*Menu*/

    ul.menu {
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }

    label.show-menu {
        display: none;
    }

    input.show-menu {
        display: none;
    }


a:visited {
        border: none;
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
ul.menu > ul {
    margin-left: 80px;
    border: none;

}
ul.menu > ul li
 {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 80px;
}
ul.menu > ul {
    position: relative;

}
ul.menu > ul li {
    font-size: 30px;
    min-height: 1px;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    padding: 10px;
}
ul.menu > ul ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
ul.menu > ul ul li {
    float: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 30px;
}

ul.menu > ul li:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
ul.menu > ul li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
}


ul.menu ul > li > ul > li {
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
ul.menu ul > li > ul > li > a {
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
    display: block;
}

 #Logo {
        float: left;
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 56px;
        height: 79px;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the media query will fix the problem, I have to adjust the tags in the css file of the desktop version to the tags used in the new html menu.

Comment: Sorry didn't see that the HTML changed, I would still suggest to use the same HTML and apply different CSS. It would be less maintainable to use different HTML. Also, it is usually easier to design your page with mobile first in mind. So you could start with your friend solution, and modify its CSS to properly fit with desktop resolution.

Comment: Sadly I have to have the website finished in 2 days, I cannot start all over again.